# Expectation Value of displacement to the $n$th power quantum harmonic oscillator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, harmonic-oscillator

Is there a closed-form expression for $\langle x^n\rangle$ for the ground state quantum harmonic oscillator, where $n =$ even integer $>0$? I am attempting to pursue this with rising and lowering operators but the foiling is getting out of hand.

I would like $$\langle0 | x^n |0\rangle = \underline{\qquad\qquad}\,, n={2,4,6,8,\dots}$$
Example: 
$$\langle0 | x^2 |0\rangle = \langle0|\left[\sqrt{\frac{\hbar}{2m\omega}}\left(a^{\dagger} + a\right)\right]^{2}| 0\rangle = \frac{1}{2\alpha},$$ where $\alpha = m\omega/\hbar$

Comment: There are closed form expressions for the WF of the harmonic oscillator, you can find them anywhere online. And as a hint the ground state is symmetric across the origin

Comment: Apologies, I edited to make the question more clear.  I was looking for the expression for the average displacement^nth power

Comment: Have a look at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/460206/135433

Comment: Have you considered a solution using induction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the answer without raising and lowering operators, by directly calculating the the overlap integral using the identity
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}dx \ x^{2n} \ e^{-\alpha x^2} = \frac{(2n-1)!!}{(2\alpha)^n} \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}\ ,$$
which you can prove by induction or just look up in a table of integrals such as Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.

Comment: does there exist a similar way for excited states also? I was looking up for Integrals with Hermite polynomials.

Comment: @Galilean Yes. https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/460206/135433