# Expectation value for higher order operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, hilbert-space, operators

I would like to evaluate the following operator on a coherent state $|\alpha\rangle$
\begin{equation}
\langle \alpha|(a^\dagger+a)^{2n} |\alpha\rangle
\end{equation}
Using the property 
\begin{equation}
(a^\dagger+a)^n =\sum_{k=0}^{n/2}\sum_{s=0}^{n-2k}\frac{n!}{2^{k} k!s!(n-2k-s)!}(a^{\dagger})^{s} a^{n-2k-s}
\end{equation}
I reached to 
\begin{equation}
 e^{-|\alpha|^{2}/2}\sum_{k=0}^{n}\sum_{s=0}^{2n-2k}\frac{n!}{2^{k} k!s!(n-2k-s)!}\frac{\alpha^n}{\sqrt{n!}}(a^{\dagger})^{s} a^{2n-2k-s}|n\rangle
\end{equation}
of course the term $\langle \alpha|(a^{\dagger})^s$ is included on the left. The question is how to evaluate $a^{2n-2k-s}|n\rangle$. Any comments or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Actually, I think this approach is a bit too cumbersome. Take a look of these lecture notes [link](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/physics/8-05-quantum-physics-ii-fall-2013/lecture-notes/MIT8_05F13_Chap_06.pdf), specially equation 4.29, where a similar expectation value is computed, and take it from there.

Comment: Quick hint: Use $(\frac{d}{dx})^n e_{}^{x(a^\dagger + a)}|_{\{x=0\}}=(a^\dagger + a)^n$ and a simple expression for $\langle \alpha | e_{}^{x(a^\dagger + a)}| \alpha \rangle$.

Comment: Is the operator Hermitian? Are these raising and lowering operators when applied to coherent states? If so, you can prove that If the operators are not products raised to the same power, they have an expectation value of zero. In other words, you'd only have to consider $s=n-k$.

Comment: @Romero, yes it's Hermitian & a is the lowering operator

Comment: @R.Romero sorry, but that is not true. You seem to think that $a|\alpha\rangle$ is orthogonal to $|\alpha\rangle$, but in fact $|\alpha\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $a$.

Comment: @Sunyam I think that could be an answer.

Comment: Will try write it up once I get some time.

Comment: If there's an equal number of $a$ and its inverse the net effect on a given eigenstate is to yield a multiple of it, whereas if there's an uneven amount, the series of operators produces a different state orthogonal to the original state, yielding zero upon taking the inner product.

Comment: @R.Romero Sorry, I might have misunderstood you. If you mean an eigenstate of $H$ (not of $a$) in "the net effect on a given eigenstate", you are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Recall that $|\alpha\rangle$ is an eigenstate of $a$:
$$ a|\alpha\rangle = \alpha |\alpha\rangle \quad \text{and} \quad \langle \alpha | a^\dagger = \alpha^\ast \langle \alpha | . $$
Therefore, an expression like $a^{n-2k-s} |\alpha\rangle$ is substantially easier to evaluate if you do *not* expand $|\alpha\rangle$ in the number basis ($|n\rangle$).

---

In response to the question "how to evaluate $a^{n-2k+s}|\alpha\rangle$:
Well, $a|\alpha\rangle = \alpha |\alpha\rangle$ (and $\alpha$ is just a complex number). Thus $a^2|\alpha\rangle = a(\alpha |\alpha\rangle) = \alpha^2|\alpha\rangle$. Do you see the pattern?

Comment: that's the question. I already reached using the above property

Comment: @user0322 I don't understand your comment. What is the question?

Comment: I mean the steps after that (with expanding the state in number basis)

Comment: @user0322 My hint is not to expand the state in the number basis.

Comment: I completely agree

Comment: could you write me more information (references) on how to evaluate $a^{n-2k-s} |\alpha\rangle$?

Comment: @user0322 edited

Answer (score 0):

Here a method based on generating function is given for calculating matrix elements of the sort (scheme is analogous to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/460206))
$$\langle\{\alpha_{i}^{}\}|\prod_{i=1}^{N}\left[\lambda_{i}^{}a_{i}^{\dagger}+\mu_{i}^{}a_{i}^{}\right]_{}^{n_{i}^{}}|\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\} \rangle,$$
where $a_{i}^{\dagger}$ and $a_{i}^{}$ are bosonic creation and annhilation operators and $|\{\alpha_{i}^{}\}\rangle$ is the bosonic (non-normalized) coherent state i.e., 
$$a_{k}^{}|\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\}\rangle={\alpha_{k}^{'}}_{}^{}|\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\}\rangle$$ defined as
$$|\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\}\rangle=e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\alpha_{i}^{'}a_{i}^{\dagger}}|\textit{vac}\rangle.$$ 
(i) Define a generating function as follows:
$$\mathcal{G}\left[\{\alpha_{i}^{}\},\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\}|\{\lambda_{i}^{}\},\{\mu_{i}^{}\}|\{z_{i}^{}\}\right]=\langle\{\alpha_{i}^{}\}|e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}z_{i}^{}\left[\lambda_{i}^{}a_{i}^{\dagger}+\mu_{i}^{}a_{i}^{}\right]_{}^{}}|\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\} \rangle,$$ using which the sought after matrix elements can be obtained as:
$$\langle\{\alpha_{i}^{}\}|\prod_{i=1}^{N}\left[\lambda_{i}^{}a_{i}^{\dagger}+\mu_{i}^{}a_{i}^{}\right]_{}^{n_{i}^{}}|\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\} \rangle=\prod_{i=1}^{N}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial z_{i}^{}}\right]_{}^{n_{i}^{}}\mathcal{G}\left[\{\alpha_{i}^{}\},\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\}|\{\lambda_{i}^{}\},\{\mu_{i}^{}\}|\{z_{i}^{}\}\right]\Bigg|_{\{z_{i}^{}\} \to\{0\}}^{}.$$
(ii) Use [Baker–Campbell–Hausdorff formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baker%E2%80%93Campbell%E2%80%93Hausdorff_formula):
$$e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}z_{i}^{}\left[\lambda_{i}^{}a_{i}^{\dagger}+\mu_{i}^{}a_{i}^{}\right]_{}^{}}=e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_{i}^{}z_{i}^{}a_{i}^{\dagger}}e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mu_{i}^{}z_{i}^{}a_{i}^{}}e_{}^{\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_{i}^{}\mu_{i}^{}{z_{i}^{}}_{}^{2}}$$ and

$$e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mu_{i}^{}z_{i}^{}a_{i}^{}}|\{\alpha_{i}^{}\}\rangle=e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\mu_{i}^{}z_{i}^{}\alpha_{i}^{}}|\{\alpha_{i}^{}\}\rangle,$$

$$\langle\{\alpha_{i}^{}\}|\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\} \rangle=e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}\alpha_{i}^{'}}.$$
(iii) Show that 
$$\mathcal{G}\left[\{\alpha_{i}^{}\},\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\}|\{\lambda_{i}^{}\},\{\mu_{i}^{}\}|\{z_{i}^{}\}\right]=e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}{\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}\alpha_{i}^{'}}e_{}^{\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\lambda_{i}^{}\mu_{i}^{}{z_{i}^{}}_{}^{2}}e_{}^{\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}z_{i}^{}\left[\lambda_{i}^{}{\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}+\mu_{i}^{}\alpha_{i}^{'}\right]}.$$ 
This upon simplification this becomes 
$$\mathcal{G}\left[\{\alpha_{i}^{}\},\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\}|\{\lambda_{i}^{}\},\{\mu_{i}^{}\}|\{z_{i}^{}\}\right]=e_{}^{-\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[{\left(\lambda_{i}^{}{\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}\right)}_{}^{2}+{\left(\mu_{i}^{}\alpha_{i}^{'}\right)}_{}^{2}+2\left(\lambda_{i}^{}\mu_{i}^{}-1\right){\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}\alpha_{i}^{'}\right]}e_{}^{\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[z_{i}^{}+\left(\lambda_{i}^{}{\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}+\mu_{i}^{}\alpha_{i}^{'}\right)\right]_{}^{2}}.$$
The normalized coherent state variant of the above formula is
$$\tilde{\mathcal{G}}\left[\{\alpha_{i}^{}\},\{\alpha_{i}^{'}\}|\{\lambda_{i}^{}\},\{\mu_{i}^{}\}|\{z_{i}^{}\}\right]=e_{}^{-\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[{\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}\left({\lambda_{i}^{}}_{}^{2}{\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}+{\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{}\right)+\left({\alpha_{i}^{'}}_{}^{*}+{\mu_{i}^{}}_{}^{2}{\alpha_{i}^{'}}_{}^{}\right)\alpha_{i}^{'}+2\left(\lambda_{i}^{}\mu_{i}^{}-1\right){\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}\alpha_{i}^{'}\right]}e_{}^{\frac{1}{2}\displaystyle\sum_{i=1}^{N}\left[z_{i}^{}+\left(\lambda_{i}^{}{\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}+\mu_{i}^{}\alpha_{i}^{'}\right)\right]_{}^{2}}.$$
(iv) The specific case OP is interested in is 
$$\tilde{\mathcal{G}}\left[\alpha_{}^{},\alpha_{}^{}|1,1|z_{}^{}\right]=e_{}^{\left[\frac{1}{2}z_{}^{2}+z_{}^{}\left({\alpha_{i}^{}}_{}^{*}+\alpha_{}^{}\right)\right]_{}^{}}.$$
The above expression for $\tilde{\mathcal{G}}\left[\alpha_{}^{},\alpha_{}^{}|1,1|z_{}^{}\right]$ is closely related to [Hermite Polynomials generating function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermite_polynomials#Generating_function), hence averages of the sort $\langle \alpha| \left[a_{}^{\dagger}+a_{}^{}\right]_{}^{n}|\alpha\rangle$, OP is after can be obtained in closed form in terms of Hermite polynomials.