# Sixth moment of harmonic oscillator

Tags: quantum-mechanics, schroedinger-equation, harmonic-oscillator

Denote by $\vert n\rangle$ the eigenstates of the harmonic oscillator in $1D$.
I am wondering if there is an explicit expression for

$$\langle m \vert x^6 \vert n\rangle=?$$

It is obvious from symmetry considerations that this expectation value vanishes unless

$m $ and $n$ are both either even or odd (symmetry) and $\vert m-n \vert \le 6
$ (orthgonality of Hermite polynomials)

However, I could not find an explicit expression for this expectation value. Is there a reference?

Thus, by self-adjointness it would be sufficient to have the following matrix elements

$$\langle n \vert x^6 \vert n\rangle, \langle n-2 \vert x^6 \vert n\rangle,\langle n-4 \vert x^6 \vert n\rangle, \langle n-6 \vert x^6 \vert n\rangle.$$

Does anybody know a reference for this?

Comment: Show your efforts.

Comment: You can use result arrived at https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/460206. Ofcourse you have to rescale the coordinates before using the formula arrived at there.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/510950 can also be useful.

Comment: Are you familiar with $\frac{a+ a^\dagger}{2}|n\rangle= \tfrac{1}{2}(\sqrt{n+1}|n+1\rangle+\sqrt{n}|n-1\rangle)$?

Comment: Now, what is $x^3|n\rangle$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a one dimensional harmonic oscillator,the energy eigenfunctions are given by..
$$\psi_n =  \Biggr(\frac{m\omega}{\hbar\pi }\Biggr)^{1/4}\frac{1} {\sqrt {2^n n!}}  \exp \Biggr(\frac{-\xi^2}{2}\Biggr)H_n(x)$$

$$\langle m \vert x^6 \vert n \rangle = \Biggr(\frac{m\omega}{\hbar\pi }\Biggr)^{1/2}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt {2^m m!}}  \exp \Biggr(\frac{-\xi^2}{2}\Biggr)H_m(\xi) \cdot x^6 \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt {2^n n!}}  \exp \Biggr(\frac{-\xi^2}{2}\Biggr)H_n(\xi)$$

$$ =\Biggr(\frac{m\omega}{\hbar\pi }\Biggr)^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt {2^{m+n} m!n!}}    \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp \Biggr(\frac{-\xi^2}{2}\Biggr)H_m(\xi) \cdot x^6 \cdot    \exp \Biggr(\frac{-\xi^2}{2}\Biggr)H_n(\xi)$$

$$ =\Biggr(\frac{m\omega}{\hbar\pi }\Biggr)^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt {2^{m+n} m!n!}}  \  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}  H_m(\xi) \cdot x^6 \cdot    \exp  ( {-\xi^2}  )H_n(\xi) d\xi$$

$$= \Biggr(\frac{m\omega}{\hbar\pi }\Biggr)^{1/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt {2^{m+n} m!n!}}    \cdot I$$

Take note, that I didn't change the variable of integration completely, I hope you can do that:)

Now if we can express $x^6$ as a linear combination of Hermite polynomials, we can solve the integral using linearization formula
$$\xi^6 =  \frac{1}{64}\Biggr(H_6(\xi) +30H_4(\xi) + 180H_2(\xi) + 120H_0(\xi) \Biggr)$$
$$I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H_m(\xi)\xi^6  H_n(\xi) w(i) d\xi$$
$$I =\frac{1}{64}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} H_m(\xi)\Biggr(H_6(\xi) +30H_4(\xi) + 180H_2(\xi) + 120H_0(\xi) \Biggr)  H_n(\xi) w(i)$$
where $w(i)$ is weight function equal to $e^{-x^2}$
Now you can compute this integral using the linearization formula's which can be found in many trustable sources
$$
\int_{-\infty}^\infty H_\ell(x) \, H_m(x) \, H_n(x) \, e^{-x^2} dx = \frac{2^{(\ell+m+n)/2}\ell! m! n! \sqrt{\pi}}{(\frac{\ell+m-n}{2})!(\frac{m+n-\ell}{2})!(\frac{n+\ell-m}{2})!}
$$